# AWS Client gateway API Issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-sdk

I am trying to execute AWS REST API from node js using AWS client gateway APIs.

Here is the code:

```js
var apigClientFactory = require('aws-api-gateway-client').default;

let awsbody = JSON.parse(process.argv[2].split('\\').join('') || '{}');

//                                            Loggin to confirm Input

var apigClient = apigClientFactory.newClient({
    invokeUrl: awsbody.endPoint, // REQUIRED
    accessKey: awsbody.awsAccessKey, // REQUIRED
    secretKey: awsbody.awsSecreteKey, // REQUIRED
    region: awsbody.awsRegion, // REQUIRED: The region where the API is deployed.
    retryCondition: (err) => { // OPTIONAL: Callback to further control if request should be retried.  Uses axon-retry plugin.
        return err.response && err.response.status === 500;
    }
});


var pathParams = awsbody.awsPathParams;
// Template syntax follows url-template https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-template
var pathTemplate = awsbody.awsPathTemplate; // '/api/v1/sites'
var method = awsbody.method; // 'POST';
var additionalParams = { queryParams: awsbody.awsAdditionalParams };
//var additionalParams = {};

var body = awsbody.requestBody;
var output = {};

apigClient.invokeApi(pathParams, pathTemplate, method, additionalParams, body)
    .then(function(result) {
        // return JSON.parse(result.data);
        output.state = result.response.data,
            output.header = result.response.headers;
        return output
            //    console.log(result.response.headers)

    }).catch(function(result) {
        //console.log(result)
        // console.log(result.response.data)
        // console.log(result.response.status + " - " + 
        result.response.statusText)

        output.state = result.response.data,
            output.responsecode = result.response.status,
            output.responsetext = result.response.statusText;
        return output
    });
```

Post execution getting below Error:

Error Message: (node:3424) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
at C:\Servicenow\nodejs\awsInvokeRestapi.js:63:40
at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:77:7)
(node:3424) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:3424) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

But If I just return result, getting output without any issue. But here I am trying to read only necessary information from result.

Here is the entire Result: I just need data object.

```js
{ Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (C:\Users\kp250041\desktop\Myfiles\node_modules\aws-api-gateway-client\node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (C:\Users\kp250041\desktop\Myfiles\node_modules\aws-api-gateway-client\node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:18:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (C:\Users\kp250041\desktop\Myfiles\node_modules\aws-api-gateway-client\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\http.js:201:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:187:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1094:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
  config:
   { adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
     transformRequest: { '0': [Function: transformRequest] },
     transformResponse: { '0': [Function: transformResponse] },
     timeout: 0,
     xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
     xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
     maxContentLength: -1,
     validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
     headers:
      { Accept: 'application/json',
        'x-amz-date': '20190122T211036Z',
        Authorization:
         'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIAJ4Y5DGRDNBQ2HBYA/20190122/us-west-2/execute-api/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=accept;host;x-amz-date, Signature=dfa8326d867efde822f2974ab7b197a7f8fd26189a09e558399cb8339cb249f1',        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'User-Agent': 'axios/0.18.0' },
     method: 'delete',
     data: undefined,
     url:
      'https://vs2i50xvo4.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/qa/transit-connectivity/api/v1/sites/TDCLOUDAMTD05?change_request=%5Bobject%20Object%5D' },
  request:
   ClientRequest {
     _events:
      { socket: [Function],
        abort: [Function],
        aborted: [Function],
        error: [Function],
        timeout: [Function],
        prefinish: [Function: requestOnPrefinish] },
     _eventsCount: 6,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     output: [],
     outputEncodings: [],
     outputCallbacks: [],
     outputSize: 0,
     writable: true,
     _last: true,
     chunkedEncoding: false,
     shouldKeepAlive: false,
     useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
     sendDate: false,
     _removedConnection: false,
     _removedContLen: false,
     _removedTE: false,
     _contentLength: 0,
     _hasBody: true,
     _trailer: '',
     finished: true,
     _headerSent: true,
     socket:
      TLSSocket {
        _tlsOptions: [Object],
        _secureEstablished: true,
        _securePending: false,
        _newSessionPending: false,
        _controlReleased: true,
        _SNICallback: null,
        servername: 'vs2i50xvo4.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
        alpnProtocol: false,
        authorized: true,
        authorizationError: null,
        encrypted: true,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 8,
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: [TLSWrap],
        _parent: null,
        _host: 'vs2i50xvo4.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
        _readableState: [ReadableState],
        readable: true,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [WritableState],
        writable: false,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: undefined,
        _server: null,
        ssl: [TLSWrap],
        _requestCert: true,
        _rejectUnauthorized: true,
        parser: null,
        _httpMessage: [Circular],
        [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 6,
        [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
        [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
        [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
        [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
        [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object] },
     connection:
      TLSSocket {
        _tlsOptions: [Object],
        _secureEstablished: true,
        _securePending: false,
        _newSessionPending: false,
        _controlReleased: true,
        _SNICallback: null,
        servername: 'vs2i50xvo4.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
        alpnProtocol: false,
        authorized: true,
        authorizationError: null,
        encrypted: true,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 8,
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: [TLSWrap],
        _parent: null,
        _host: 'vs2i50xvo4.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
        _readableState: [ReadableState],
        readable: true,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [WritableState],
        writable: false,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: undefined,
        _server: null,
        ssl: [TLSWrap],
        _requestCert: true,
        _rejectUnauthorized: true,
        parser: null,
        _httpMessage: [Circular],
        [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 6,
        [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
        [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
        [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
        [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
        [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object] },
     _header:
      'DELETE /qa/transit-connectivity/api/v1/sites/TDCLOUDAMTD05?change_request=%5Bobject%20Object%5D HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept: application/json\r\nx-amz-date: 20190122T211036Z\r\nAuthorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIAJ4Y5DGRDNBQ2HBYA/20190122/us-west-2/execute-api/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=accept;host;x-amz-date, Signature=dfa8326d867efde822f2974ab7b197a7f8fd26189a09e558399cb8339cb249f1\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nUser-Agent: axios/0.18.0\r\nHost: vs2i50xvo4.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n',
     _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
     agent:
      Agent {
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        defaultPort: 443,
        protocol: 'https:',
        options: [Object],
        requests: {},
        sockets: [Object],
        freeSockets: {},
        keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
        keepAlive: false,
        maxSockets: Infinity,
        maxFreeSockets: 256,
        maxCachedSessions: 100,
        _sessionCache: [Object] },
     socketPath: undefined,
     timeout: undefined,
     method: 'DELETE',
     path:
      '/qa/transit-connectivity/api/v1/sites/TDCLOUDAMTD05?change_request=%5Bobject%20Object%5D',
     _ended: true,
     res:
      IncomingMessage {
        _readableState: [ReadableState],
        readable: false,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 3,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        socket: [TLSSocket],
        connection: [TLSSocket],
        httpVersionMajor: 1,
        httpVersionMinor: 1,
        httpVersion: '1.1',
        complete: true,
        headers: [Object],
        rawHeaders: [Array],
        trailers: {},
        rawTrailers: [],
        aborted: false,
        upgrade: false,
        url: '',
        method: null,
        statusCode: 404,
        statusMessage: 'Not Found',
        client: [TLSSocket],
        _consuming: false,
        _dumped: false,
        req: [Circular],
        responseUrl:
         'https://vs2i50xvo4.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/qa/transit-connectivity/api/v1/sites/TDCLOUDAMTD05?change_request=%5Bobject%20Object%5D',
        redirects: [] },
     aborted: undefined,
     timeoutCb: null,
     upgradeOrConnect: false,
     parser: null,
     maxHeadersCount: null,
     _redirectable:
      Writable {
        _writableState: [WritableState],
        writable: true,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _options: [Object],
        _redirectCount: 0,
        _redirects: [],
        _requestBodyLength: 0,
        _requestBodyBuffers: [],
        _onNativeResponse: [Function],
        _currentRequest: [Circular],
        _currentUrl:
         'https://vs2i50xvo4.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/qa/transit-connectivity/api/v1/sites/TDCLOUDAMTD05?change_request=%5Bobject%20Object%5D' },
     [Symbol(isCorked)]: false,
     [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]:
      { accept: [Array],
        'x-amz-date': [Array],
        authorization: [Array],
        'content-type': [Array],
        'user-agent': [Array],
        host: [Array] } },
  response:
   { status: 404,
     statusText: 'Not Found',
     headers:
      { 'content-type': 'application/json',
        'content-length': '53',
        connection: 'close',
        date: 'Tue, 22 Jan 2019 21:10:37 GMT',
        'x-amzn-requestid': '2a1ca05d-1e8a-11e9-8b27-cd6ea47769e0',
        'x-amz-apigw-id': 'T7IAEEB2PHcFWHA=',
        'x-amzn-trace-id': 'Root=1-5c4786cd-94386d24d094bb8aa6614efa;Sampled=0',
        'x-cache': 'Error from cloudfront',
        via:
         '1.1 4a283201d995829e522a4b36763be15d.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)',
        'x-amz-cf-id': 'xqR_nC0-wVzDYVLJUEaqcej_I2jIYu3DurnjwtQ1WHwtm9Vl_D1USw==' },
     config:
      { adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
        transformRequest: [Object],
        transformResponse: [Object],
        timeout: 0,
        xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
        xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
        maxContentLength: -1,
        validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
        headers: [Object],
        method: 'delete',
        data: undefined,
        url:
         'https://vs2i50xvo4.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/qa/transit-connectivity/api/v1/sites/TDCLOUDAMTD05?change_request=%5Bobject%20Object%5D' },
     request:
      ClientRequest {
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 6,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        _last: true,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: false,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
        sendDate: false,
        _removedConnection: false,
        _removedContLen: false,
        _removedTE: false,
        _contentLength: 0,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: true,
        _headerSent: true,
        socket: [TLSSocket],
        connection: [TLSSocket],
        _header:
         'DELETE /qa/transit-connectivity/api/v1/sites/TDCLOUDAMTD05?change_request=%5Bobject%20Object%5D HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept: application/json\r\nx-amz-date: 20190122T211036Z\r\nAuthorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIAJ4Y5DGRDNBQ2HBYA/20190122/us-west-2/execute-api/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=accept;host;x-amz-date, Signature=dfa8326d867efde822f2974ab7b197a7f8fd26189a09e558399cb8339cb249f1\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nUser-Agent: axios/0.18.0\r\nHost: vs2i50xvo4.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n',
        _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
        agent: [Agent],
        socketPath: undefined,
        timeout: undefined,
        method: 'DELETE',
        path:
         '/qa/transit-connectivity/api/v1/sites/TDCLOUDAMTD05?change_request=%5Bobject%20Object%5D',
        _ended: true,
        res: [IncomingMessage],
        aborted: undefined,
        timeoutCb: null,
        upgradeOrConnect: false,
        parser: null,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        _redirectable: [Writable],
        [Symbol(isCorked)]: false,
        [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: [Object] },
     data: { status: 'failed', message: 'resource not found' } } }
```

Comment: This question doesn't appear to have anything to do with PowerShell.

Comment: @p.s.w.g or about how to start a node app from powershell

Comment: According to the error the bug is here: `output.state = result.response.data` It seems that `result.response` is `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: `response` is just a text dumped at error time, not a key. Try accessing `result.data`, `result.statusText` etc., this should do it.

Comment: @StockOverflaw thanks for input. It actually worked. :)